# Linux creates a small icon while running c++ compiled binary file

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have the below line to run a binary file in linux,

```
binaryFile $2 & > logfiles.txt
```

Whenever it is executed it creates a small icon on the left top corner of the screen (attached image),[image]

I want to run the binary without the icon(the small line).

Is there anyway to do that?Please help.

**EDIT:**

I got to know `XtRealizeWidget` is creating that small icon,

In the code,
a topLevel window is created using `XtAppInitialize` and `XtRealizeWidget(topLevel)`is called which creates it.

Is there a way to disable the icon via code.

Comment: What is this "binary file"?

Comment: Linux doesn't create that icon, your desktop system or window manager (which may well run on top of Linux) does. Or, maybe the program you are running does? First step on the way to a solution is to find out which is the case.

Comment: Perhaps, your binaryFile is GUI executable. To figure this out use readelf command with -d key. If you'll find some X dependencies, then it's true.

Comment: Okay! I Got to know this is because of two functions XtRealizeWidget and XIconifyWindow. @UlrichEckhardt could you please tell me what these two methods does.